# git where I don't want it

Tags: git

I have just discovered that, several years ago, my entire home directory got entangled with a git repository. How do I remove that git repository, without affecting anything else, including other git repositories (which I definitely want to keep) in subfolders of my home directory?

Even more confusingly for me, `git log` shows a friend's email address (this mess probably happened when I was working on a project they had started), but none of `git config --get remote.origin.url`, `git remote -v`, `git remote show` etc. show anything; and `git remote show origin` shows an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the `.git` directory of your home directory.

```
$ rm -rf .git
```